# Create array in Excel with values from non-adjacent cells

Tags: arrays, excel-2016

Simply put, I need help making Arrays from values in non-adjacent cells, to be able to use the correlation formula. See picture for the concrete problem. Thanks in advance!

[Excel snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg7jh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

in I2 put `=D4` , I3 put `=D9` , I4 put `=D15` , then in J2 put `=G6` , J3 put `=G11` , J4 put `=G17` . Then select I2:I4 and J2:J4 as your array in the CORREL() function.

Comment: Thanks you! I will see if this works next time I'm working on the project

Comment: You may click on the 'tick' if it works. or share if it doesn't . You're welcomed.